# Pushing local branch to remote branch

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I created new repository in my Github repository.

Using the gitpython library I'm able to get this repository. Then I create new branch, add new file, commit and try to push to the new branch.

Please check be code below:

```
import git
import random
import os

repo_name = 'test'
branch_name = 'feature4'

remote_repo_addr_git = 'git@repo:DevOps/z_sandbox1.git'

no = random.randint(0,1000)
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(remote_repo_addr_git, repo_name)
new_branch = repo.create_head(branch_name)
repo.head.set_reference(new_branch)
os.chdir(repo_name)
open("parasol" + str(no), "w+").write(str(no)) # this is added
print repo.active_branch
repo.git.add(A=True)
repo.git.commit(m='okej')
repo.git.push(u='origin feature4')
```

Everything working fine until last push method. I got this error:

> stderr: 'fatal: 'origin feature4' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.'

I'm able to run this method from command line and it's working fine:

```
git puth -u origin feature4
```

But it doesn't work in Python.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
repo.git.push("origin", "feature4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Useful documentation for fetch/pull/push operations with gitpython:
https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=index.fetch#git.remote.Remote.fetch

```py
from git import GitCommandError, Repo

repo_name = 'test'
branch_name = 'feature4'
remote_repo_addr_git = 'git@repo:DevOps/z_sandbox1.git'

# clone repo
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(remote_repo_addr_git, repo_name)

# refspec is a sort of mapping between remote:local references
refspec = f'refs/heads/{branch_name}:refs/heads/{branch_name}'

# get branch
try:
    # if exists pull the branch
    # the refspec here means: grab the {branch_name} branch head
    # from the remote repo and store it as my {branch_name} branch head
    repo.remotes.origin.pull(refspec)
except GitCommandError:
    # if not exists create it
    repo.create_head(branch_name)

# checkout branch
branch = repo.heads[branch_name]
branch.checkout()

# modify files
with open(f'{repo_name}/hello.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('hello')

# stage & commit & push
repo.index.add('**')
repo.index.commit('added good manners')
# refspec here means: publish my {branch_name} branch head
# as {branch_name} remote branch
repo.remotes.origin.push(refspec)
```